# Communication between child processes on TCP socket

Tags: c++, signals, fork, tcpsocket

I have a synchronous server program using Linux TCP socket in C++. I'm using `fork()` to handle connections from different hosts. I would like to notify all of the child processes when specified action is performed by some of the connected hosts. What is the best way to propagate the information?

Comment: *What is the best way to propagate the information?* Define "best".

Comment: easiest and safe. I just want to notify all other hosts that one of the connected host posted something

Comment: lets say I want to pass an integer value between the processes. Is it better to use shared memory or create a signal somehow?

Comment: @3va You can use sockets. See [`socketpair`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/socketpair).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614895/what-library-can-i-use-to-do-simple-lightweight-message-passing